# Why is JRuby giving me an "incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, jruby

I have a Rails 3.2.8 app. It runs under both Ruby 1.9.3 and JRuby 1.6.7.2 in 1.9-compatible mode. Inserting into a database sometimes crashes under JRuby.

Here's my en.yml file:

```
en:
  moo: "you’re"
  meep: "you"
  bar: "\"Booón\""
  baz: "Booón"
```

suppose I have a Message object that has two attributes, sender and subject. Here are a few possible combinations of sender and subject

```
msg = Message.new(subject: "sblah", sender: I18n.t("bar"))
msg.save

msg = Message.new(subject: "sblah", sender: I18n.t("baz"))
msg.save

msg = Message.new(subject: I18n.t("moo"), sender: I18n.t("baz"))
msg.save

msg = Message.new(subject: I18n.t("moo"), sender: "temp")
msg.save

msg = Message.new(subject: I18n.t("meep"), sender: I18n.t("bar"))
msg.save

# Mystery crash
msg = Message.new(subject: I18n.t("moo"), sender: I18n.t("bar"))
msg.save
```

When running under JRuby 1.6.7.2 (with 1.9 compatibility), the last one causes a crash. The crash *does not occur* with MRI 1.9.3p194.

It seems to require a combination of (an accented character and quotes) and (a curly apostrophe) to trigger the crash. Take any one of those things away. No crash.

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
    from org/jruby/RubyString.java:2926:in `gsub'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.2/lib/arjdbc/mysql/adapter.rb:485:in `exec_insert'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:90:in `insert'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:19:in `insert'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/relation.rb:66:in `insert'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:366:in `create'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `create'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:406:in `_run__142677804__create__486269792__callbacks'
    from org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:390:in `_run_create_callbacks'
    from org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    from /Users/paul/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
... 17 levels...
```

Here's the code that crashed:

```
480       def exec_insert(sql, name, binds)
481         binds = binds.dup
482 
483         # Pretend to support bind parameters
484         unless binds.empty?
485           sql = sql.gsub('?') { quote(*binds.shift.reverse) }                                       
486         end
487         execute sql, name
488       end
```

Comment: [This](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/17/encodings-unabridged/) article may give you a bit of a clue...  Note that `ASCII-8BIT` should be understood as 'some unclear encoding', which will be more liberally returned by Java than standard ruby

Comment: How are you invoking 1.9?  `JRUBY_OPTS` or jruby switch?